# Importance of same RPM in a NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage

I am thinking of buying a completely new NAS with 4 bays. I would like to fill each bay with a 12 TB HDD, and apply RAID 5.

Most often it will be accessed from 2 computers at most. I searched for 10 GB LAN routers but did not find any, not even at very high prices; so I assume that the 1 Gbps network speed will be a bottleneck in the next 5-10 years (is that correct?).

I found that there are two spindle speeds available: WD Red runs at 5400 RPM, all the others at 7200 RPM. Considering the above bottleneck, I would prefer the 5400 RPM: lower noise, lower energy consumption, maybe better MTBF (do I see it right?).

On the other hand, I would like to diversify, and buy from multiple manufacturers. Does it have any disadvantages (or advantages) if the RPM is different? If it is less recommended, then what is more important: (1) having the same RPM, or (2) diversification between manufacturers (and not just between production series)?

Comment: RAID 5 is dead. You only use it on drives larger than 1TB if you don't mind losing all your data.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I read something about the risk of URE during rebuild. What I don't see (I found different opinions on that) is what happens if there is a URE during rebuild: Do I lose all data on the NAS or only one sector, so that one file is corrupted (or maybe the directory structure if I'm unlucky)?

Comment: No, you lose _everything_.

Comment: Thanks, and if I use RAIDZ instead of hardware RAID5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (do I see it right?).

No, you do not. And you seem not to like to read. Let me explain:

> lower noise, lower energy consumption, maybe better MTBF

ALL of those are in the data sheets. Take the data sheets of the discs you want, LOOK AT THE NUMBERS. Also - discs may be of different make. Regular cheap end user "crap"? NEARLINE discs with a LOT better MTBF and reliability? Again, all that is in the data sheets. Read them.

> On the other hand, I would like to diversify, and buy from multiple manufacturers.

It is always a great idea to introduce additional possible failures into a system. OUCH. Especialyl given that there are 3 or so serious manufacturers to start with and depending on what you require as platform you basically end up with Seagate ANYWAY.

> Does it have any disadvantages (or advantages) if the RPM is different?

Outside the obvious that RPM directly correlate with IOPS and you basically slow down the whole system by introducing a slower discs into a Raid 5 cluster?

> (1) having the same RPM, or (2) diversification between manufacturers (and not just
> between production series)?

None of it has ANY relevance and I would remove (i.e. fire) any person stating that diversity of manufacturers is of any matter higher than actually getting the best discs for the job. You just ask for trouble, from finger pointing to the simple fact that every time I am starting to select hard discs, I mostly run down to one model being clearly the best.

As a joke I just checked one of my preferred suppliers for discs. SATA, 12TB, 3.5" - there are EXACTLY 2 SUPPLIERS. Seagate and Western Digital. THere are exafctly 2 models that are torderline good for business use, one from each - Seagate Exos X14 and WD GOld ENterprise class. Both rate same MTBF, both are 7200 RPM. WD uses more power (7 instead of 6 watt under use, both have 5 watt when not in use). Both have identical reliability ratings. And here is the funny thing: if I decide to go non-professional and use non-enterprise grade discs, I do NOT EVEN SAVE MONEY. The price is not really any differenc, in fact in some of the slower discs it is higher.

And yes, WD red is in the "garbage" bin for me. Why would I buy a WD red, that costs the same, has 5400RPM instead of 7200 and is - as per data sheet - has 10 times the error rate? Note that - your WD red, from an enterprise point of view, a seriously inferior product, which is clearly noted in the data sheet. It is garbage - 10 times the unrecoverable error rate, 1 million hours MTBF instead of 2.5 million, which is like the industry standard, and you actually pay MORE for it (compare WD Red 12tb to Seagate Exos X14 - list prices in Germany 354 for the first, 324 for the later. Choosing the red one is legally gross neglect. It is basically a relabelled end user drive sold with a slightly higher warranty but lacking the higher technical specs of the real enterprise drive.

So, no - you are on a comically wrong path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I started to compare the datasheets of available HDDs. I don't have much experience with this. For most models I found data on Power consumption while asleep and Annualized Workload (TB/year). However, WD Gold's datasheet does not indicate these numbers. Should I assume that it does not have a sleep mode (it would not be accessed during night), and that there is no limit on the annual workload? (And the same holds for Seagate Exos X14.)

Comment: No access in the night? No data reorganization, no RAID reconciliation, no backup? That is a heck of a level of bad maintenance if I ahve ever seen one.

Comment: Not every night, only once per week.

Comment: You said, there are only two manufacturers. Is Toshiba (MG07ACA12TE) a bad choice? Or is that some kind of white label product manufactured by WD or Seagate?